# JQuery-zoom dynamically change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm using jquery-zoom and I have 4 images for a product on my website, when clicking one of the 4 images, I want the main image to change to the clicked image and still zoomable with jquery-zoom, now everytime when click different images, the main image gets updated to the clicked one but it's no longer zoomable, it's only zoomable when the page reloaded... How should I make my desired effect happen? Currently my code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="product-main-image">
    <img id="product-zoomable-image"src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="无图片" class="img-responsive" data-BigImgsrc="/images/image1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="product-other-images">
    <a href="/images/image1.jpg" class="fancybox-button product-carousel-image" rel="photos-lib"><img alt="无图片" src="/images/image1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="/images/image2.jpg" class="fancybox-button product-carousel-image" rel="photos-lib"><img alt="无图片" src="/images/image2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="/images/image3.jpg" class="fancybox-button product-carousel-image" rel="photos-lib"><img alt="无图片" src="/images/image3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="/images/image4.jpg" class="fancybox-button product-carousel-image" rel="photos-lib"><img alt="无图片" src="/images/image4.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.product-carousel-image').click(function(event) {        // change image shown as product image
    var newImageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(newImageUrl)    ;
    $('#product-zoomable-image').attr('src', newImageUrl);
    $('#product-zoomable-image').trigger('zoom.destroy');
    $('#product-zoomable-image').zoom({url: newImageUrl});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out by myself, need to destroy the zoomImg first and then create another:

```
$('.product-carousel-image').click(function(event) {        // change image shown as product image
    var newImageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#product-zoomable-image').attr('src', newImageUrl);
    $('.product-main-image').trigger('zoom.destroy');
    $('.product-main-image').zoom({url: newImageUrl});
});
```